# Magento 2: addAttributeToFilter not returning any results

Tags: magento2, product-collection, eav

When I use `addAttributeToFilter` on **Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory**, with a custom attribute, I always get 0 results.

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

...

$collection = $this->productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('custom_attribute','sku'))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute',['lt' => 1]);
        }

echo count($collection); //Returns 0
```

I also tried to use the search criteria object as Konrad Siamro sugested:

```
$search_criteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
                ->addFilter('custom_attribute', 1, 'lt')
                ->create();
            $collection = $this->productRepository->getList($search_criteria);

echo $collection->getTotalCount(); //returns 0
```

But the results are the same. It works fine if I filter on a SKU, but my custom attribute returns nothing. I also tried adding the attribute to the flat product database and re indexing.

**Update:** Added code I used to create the attribute:

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'custom_attribute',
        [
            'type' => 'int',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'frontend_class' => 'validate-digits',
            'label' => 'Custom Attribute',
            'input' => 'text',
            'class' => 'class',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]
    );
```

Comment: U need to 1st check `catalog_product_entity` then respectively check on type table `int`, `varchar` & join

Answer (score 0):

Use search criteria for filtering collections.
Go to http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_understanding_object_repositories/
and look for search criteria.

Comment: I changed my code to use search criteria, results are exactly the same. (searching on SKU gives hits, searching on my custom attribute returns nothing.)

Comment: can You edit your post and show your  code? :)

Comment: I just edited my post.

Comment: $collection->getItems(); also return null?  Where are you using his code? Meaby custom attribute have some options set incorrect?

Comment: I added the code used to create the attribute as well. Can you check it for me?

Comment: Do you want to load this collection on frontend? change visible_on_front to true, and try

Comment: Already changed that and ran a reindex, but it did not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that when you create your custom_attribute its still empty:

```
'user_defined' => false,
        'default' => '',
        'searchable' => false,
```

your default value is empty, but you check if value is lower than 1

```
->addFilter('custom_attribute', 1, 'lt')
```

I tested it and result without setting any value for the custom_attribute gave as result 0 items which is the correct result. I changed for example the filter to

```
->addFilter('custom_attribute', 1, 'eq')
```

and set the custom_attribue to 1 in one Product in Admin. Result is now one.

Problem is lower than one is not "empty"

Tried it with the searchCriteriaBuilder and with addAttributeToFilter works both with changed Filters and setting the custom_attribute for example to 1.